# SP2010 "NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users" group versus the SP2013 "Everyone" group?

Tags: sharepoint-server, security, groups

In my test SharePoint 2010 instance, I notice SharePoint has a special group called `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users`

In my SharePoint 2013 instance, I notice I have a special group called `Everyone`

These two groups seem to make the concept of "Any logged in user" when in SharePoint.

Is there ever a time when SharePoint 2010 would have `Everyone` group or when SharePoint 2013 would have the `NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users`?

What else should I know about the difference between these two?

Does `Everyone` include non-authenticated users?

Answer (score 1):

The Authenticated Users group contains users who have authenticated to the domain or a domain that is trusted by the computer domain. The Authenticated Users group also includes the local computer account and the built-in SYSTEM account.

The Everyone group includes all members of the Domain Users, Authenticated Users group as well as the built-in Guest account, and several other Built-in security identifiers like SERVICE, LOCAL_SERVICE, NETWORK_SERVICE, etc.

More detailed information check the article: [Differences between Authenticated Users, Domain Users, and Everyone groups](http://godwindinesh.blogspot.sg/2015/02/differences-between-authenticated-users.html)